# Disabling drag functionality in slider beyond certain value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm creating a slider that ranges its value from 0 to 100, but users should only be able to drag between 2 to 100, the space between 0 and 2 should still be visible on the UI. How can I stop the dragging functionality once the value reaches 2?

```
       <Slider
          aria-label='DiceRoll'
          defaultValue={50}
          step={1}
          min={0}
          max={100}
          value={
            overUnder ? Number(flippedTargetNumber) : Number(targetNumber)
          }
          marks={marks}
          onChange={handleSelectionChange}>
```

I tried using `min={overUnder ? 2 : 0} max={overUnder ? 98 : 100}`

but that just limits the entire slider entirely and doesn't exactly reflect what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the min and max props as 0 and 100.
Change how the user can manipulate the value through your handleSelectionChange function, making it not ever setting a value below 2

```
const handleSelectionChange = (value) => {
  if (value > 2 && value <= 100) {
    setTargetNumber(value); // I'm assuming this is your setter
  }
}
```